# CakePHP 4 -> how to save join record

Tags: join, cakephp, orm

I'm working on a CakePHP 4 application and I've set up a join table between `Categories` and `Products` called `CategoriesProducts`.

When I'm creating a new Product with a property called `categories_products` which contains an array like:

```
[
    [
        'category_id' => `x`
    ]
]
```

What's supposed to be saved into the join table is the `category_id` with the newly generated `product_id`.

The data isn't saved to the join table.

In the saveMany function I pass the:

```
[
    'associated' => [
        'Categories'
    ]
]
```

When I try to add associated => CategoriesProducts I get an error that the relationship is not defined.

Can someone explain to me how I can fill the join table? I've setup the database and baked the models with the CakePHP helper.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to explain what exactly you want to save into the join table. Currently it looks you're just using the foreign key, but that doesn't need to be done manually, it would be created automatically when [**saving with an associated category record**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-belongstomany-associations).

Comment: Hi @ndm, thanks for your suggestion. I have updated the question, the join table consists of a category_id and a product_id. Since I'm passing the category_id and using it with a save on a newly created product I'm expecting the product_id to be generated automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the default association saving process you do not need to add data for join tables directly, instead you use the target association property and provide the primary keys of the records that you want to link.

So in your case that would probably be `categories`, eg your data for patching/creating an entity would be structured like this, where `id` is the primary key of the existing category that you want to associate to your new product:

```php
[
    // ...
    'categories' => [
        [
            'id' => 123,
        ],
    ],
]
```

The ORM will then create the proper join table record automatically.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Converting BelongsToMany Data](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-belongstomany-data)**

Comment: Thanks a lot ndm, this is the solution!